# Как вывести большое число без экспоненты?

Tags: php

Есть такой код:

```
function count_adress($n) {
return pow(2,128-$n); }
```

Функция считает по префиксу сети максимальное количество адресов. Работает корректно, но результат выводит при маленьком `$n` в формате `1.0633823966279E+37`

Как можно сделать, чтобы выводилось в другом формате `576,460,752,303,423,488`?

Первоначально значения искались в массиве по аргументу функции (в качестве ключа), может быть, лучше вернуться к такой реализации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте функции для работы с числами произвольной точности:

```
echo number_format(bcpow(2,128));
// вывыдет 340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,456
```

Функция `pow` вам не подходит, так как возвращает число с плавающей точкой (и потерянной точностью) если результат не помещается в обычное целое число типа *int*.

Comment: Спасибо большое))))